# Replicating pixels in an image and doubling its size

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I am trying to replicate each element in a matrix or image and am trying to increase the size of the image by 4.  This means that the rows and columns double in size.

I'm trying to do this by using a for loop and no array indexing. This is what I have so far.

```
function output = zoomx(img)
[r,c] = size(img);
output = img(r,c);
[r1, c1] = size(output);
for x = 1:r1
    for y = 1:c1
        j = 4*x;
        i = 4*y;
        output(j,i) = img(x,y);
    end
end
end
```

So far, what I'm trying to do is to iterate through my output matrix, and times each element by 4 but all I'm getting is a giant matrix of zeros and each element in the new matrix spaced out by 4 rows and columns of zeros and zeros in between each element.

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand. You want to make the output image 4x bigger than the input image?

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm trying to do!

Comment: @LuisMendo - The OP is requesting that they want to do it with `for` loops and no indexing.  As such, I'm assuming this is an academic exercise and I have reopened the post.

Comment: @rayryeng Sorry. I really must read more slowly; I completely missed the "using a for loop and no array indexing" part.

Comment: @LuisMendo - Hehe no problem my friend.  FWIW, I missed it too at a first glance.

Comment: You could use `for n=1, output = kron(ones(2), img); end` :-P

Comment: @LuisMendo - HAHAHAHA!

Comment: If you need to fill 4 pixels, you need to do 4 assignments.

Comment: BTW: `imresize(img, 2, 'nearest')` would be the obvious way to do this.

Comment: @knedlsepp - Certainly, but the OP wants to do it with loops.  This is more of an academic exercise than anything and that's what I would have done in practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to assume your aim is to just increase the size factor of your image by 4, meaning the the rows and columns double in size.   What you need to do is create an output image that has twice as many rows and columns from the original, then for each pixel in the original image, you need to copy the pixel from the original image to the right, bottom and bottom right locations.

As a minor note, your second line of code `output = img(r,c)` isn't correct.  This is accessing a single pixel located at the bottom left corner of the original image.  You probably meant to use `zeros`.  Also, the way you would access where to copy pixels in the output can be shown in my previous post to you when you were shrinking an image: [Subsample an image using a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28818632/subsample-an-image-using-a-for-loop) .  If you recall, the input to output mapping for the rows and columns is:

```
j = factor*(x-1) + 1;
i = factor*(y-1) + 1;
```

In our case, because you want to double the size of the image, you would set `factor = 2`.  Also, we will be reversing the operation.  We need `i` and `j` for the output image, and not access the input image.  We also need to move `i` and `j` over by `+1` to set the right, bottom and bottom right pixels of each doubled block for the output.

Therefore:

```
function output = zoomx(img)
[r,c] = size(img);
output = zeros(2*r,2*c,class(img)); %// Change
for x = 1:r %// Change
    for y = 1:c
        j = 2*(x-1) + 1; %// Change
        i = 2*(y-1) + 1; %// Change           
        output(j,i) = img(x,y); %// Top-left
        output(j+1,i) = img(x,y); %// Bottom-left
        output(j,i+1) = img(x,y); %// Top-right
        output(j+1,i+1) = img(x,y); %// Bottom-right
    end
end
end
```

## Example use:

```
>> im = imread('cameraman.tif');
>> out = zoomx(im);
>> imshow(out);
```

### Input Image:

[image]

### Output Image:

[image]

Comment: Hello again @rayryeng, just like the previous shrink question, im trying to do exactly that but with for loops. My code is this and i will explain what im trying to get out just to give you some background.

Comment: @RohanNair - Make a new question.