# Shrinking with for loops

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

[Just like the previous shrink question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28818632/subsample-an-image-using-a-for-loop), I'm trying to do exactly that, but with a slight modification and with `for` loops.

My code is this and I will explain what I'm trying to get out just to give you some background.

```
    function output = shrinkx(img)
    [r,c] = size(img);
    output = zeros(r,c);
for x = 1:r
    for y = 1:c
   i    mg = (img(x,y) + img(x+1,y) + img(x,y+1) + img(x+1,y+1))/4;
       output = img;
    end
end
end
```

What I'm trying to do is assign the `img` to the appropriate quadrants and then divide it by four but what happens is that it doesn't work since I'm past the dimensions of the image. My other approach would be to find a relationship for picking each other pixel and then implementing it into the code. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

By the way @rayryeng, you have been of great help and I appreciate what you do, but for this particular question, I was wondering if you can 'hint' me into the right direction instead of the full code. Not trying to be rude or anything! Also feel free to let me know if my approach is completely incorrect and if I need to start thinking differently since this is my first coding course. Thank you once again.

Comment: What you're doing is smoothing, not shrinking; the image dimensions do not change.

Comment: Well... I can't really "hint" it to you because all you have to do is make some modifications to your previous post and those modifications alone will give away the answer.  So my only options are to not answer at all, or to fully answer.  I've decided to write an answer to help you out because not answering is less constructive.

Comment: Your problem really isn't in syntax but in algorithm; without a clear idea of how to solve the problem your code would always be wrong. In times like these I find it helpful to think of simple examples and then expand on the solution found. Take a piece of paper and draw 4 dots on it, then think about how you would traverse the matrix 1 at a time to do what you want. Then, do the same thing with 16 dots, and write an algorithm to solve this new problem. When you compare your two solutions, you'd have an idea of how to generalize it into MxN dimensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've noticed in all of your questions you ask, you seem to have a problem with indexing.  You should really consult some MATLAB tutorials before posting any more questions here.  In any case, your code is almost correct.  You need to declare an output image that has half the dimensions of the input, then correctly index into the output at each step.  I won't go into much detail here like in my other posts because I did go into detail there regarding how to index for enlarging and shrinking images, but it looks like here that not only do you want to shrink the image, but you are doing smoothing as well.  As such, borrowing from [our previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28818632/subsample-an-image-using-a-for-loop), you would simply modify that code to include getting pixels from a 2 x 2 block.

There are only a few things you would need to change.  For one thing, you don't need `factor` as an input anymore as this is now simply 2.  In addition, you would need to make sure your output image is `double` initially so that when you are adding values and finding the local average, the image does not saturate.  You would also need to change the type of the input image to `double` as well to ensure that saturation doesn't happen.

If you set your image to be of the same type as the input image, it would inevitably saturate the output as you will exceed the maximum of that particular datatype that the image is read in as when you are performing the sum operations.  Only cast the image **at the end** when you're done with every pixel in the output:

```
function output = shrinkx(img) %// factor is not an input anymore
class_im = class(img); %// Save class of original image
img = double(img); %// Cast image to double for precision
[r, c] = size(img);

output = zeros(floor(r/2),floor(c/2)); %// Factor is now 2
[rnew, cnew] = size(output); 

for x = 1:rnew
    for y = 1:cnew
        j = 2*(x-1) + 1; %// Change - factor is 2
        i = 2*(y-1) + 1;
        output(x,y) = (img(j,i) + img(j,i+1) + img(j+1,i) + img(j+1,i+1))/4; %// Change here
    end
end

output = cast(output, class_im); %// Change

end
```

## Example use:

```
>> im = imread('cameraman.tif');
>> out = shrinkx(im);
>> imshow(out);
```

### Input

[image]

### Output

[image]

Comment: Good answer, although you pretty much wrote the whole thing for him lol. One thing I'd point out is the input image must have even dimensions otherwise `zeros(r/2,c/2)` would fail.

Comment: @Setsu - Certainly so!  I forgot to put in a `ceil` call.  Thanks for the spot!  I pretty much took the last response I wrote to him and made a few changes.  It wasn't a lot of effort for me, but the OP really needs to step up his game in learning the syntax.

Comment: Actually it should be `floor`, since you'd have an out-of-bounds error in the loop body. There's nothing you can do for the extra pixels so the best thing to do would be to just ignore them.

Comment: @Setsu - Correct on both accounts.  Thanks